# Kannel starts but doesn't create log files

Tags: smpp, kannel

When I start the kannel service with `service kannel start` everything goes OK, kannel does start, but it doesn't work. Log files aren't created and `/var/log/kannel/` directory is empty but I don't know why.

My configuration is as follows:

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
admin-password = pass
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/bearerbox.log"
log-level = 0
access-log = "/var/log/kannel/access_kannel.log"
store-file = "/var/log/kannel/store_sms"
smsbox-port = 13001
dlr-storage = internal
sms-resend-retry = 1

group = smsc
smsc-id = povoljye
smsc = smpp
host = **.***.***.***
port = 2775
smsc-username = "***"
smsc-password = "***"
address-range = ""
source-addr-ton = 0
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
system-type = VMA
throughput = 1000
reconnect-delay = 5
connection-timeout = 120
transceiver-mode = true
denied-smsc-id = kemerovo
allowed-smsc-id = povoljye
preferred-smsc-id = povoljye

group = smsc
smsc-id = kemerovo
smsc = smpp
host = ***.***.***.***
port = 3102
smsc-username = "***"
smsc-password = "***"
address-range = ""
source-addr-ton = 0
source-add-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
system-type = VMA
throughput = 1000
reconnect-delay = 5
connection-timeout = 120
transceiver-mode = true
denied-smsc-id = povoljye
allowed-smsc-id = kemerovo
preferred-smsc-id = kemerovo

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
sendsms-port = 13005
global-sender = 4105
log-file = /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log
log-level = 0
access-log = /var/log/kannel/access_smsbox.log

group = sendsms-user
username = "user1"
password = "pass"
concatenation = true
max-messages = 20
default-smsc = povoljye

group = sendsms-user
username = "user2"
password = "pass"
concatenation = true
max-messages = 20
default-smsc = kemerovo

group = sms-service
keyword = default
post-url = "http://domain.com/sms/%p/time/%t/coding/%c/smsc/%i"
concatenation = true
max-messages = 0
```

What could be the cause of this problem and how to find out more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing your `/var/log/kannel` isn't writable by the kannel user. Assuming a reasonably standard installation, you can try

```
sudo chown -R kannel:kannel /var/log/kannel
```

to make the kannel user the owner of the directory. Then restart it and the logs should appear there. Or you can try any other permission stuff to make the directory writable (`chmod`, add kannel to the owner group, or something else.)

You can also start Kannel from the command line in debug mode and see if anything interesting appears (by interesting I mean error messages about inaccessible directories or files,) e.g.:

```
/usr/local/sbin/bearerbox -v 0 -- /etc/kannel/kannel.conf
```

(That's assuming standard paths, if yours are different, you should change them.)

Comment: so, I'm fixed the problem, but don't know how.
Problem not in access. 

/usr/local/sbin/bearerbox -v 0 -- /etc/kannel/kannel.conf - here I find error, that config can not be readed.

I'm copied "povoljye" smsc block, and set "kemerovo" block in new lines.
I know, it's strange, but after this kannel started and work. So, I think, some invisible characters in my config here.

Comment: What is "-v 0" ?
By default, Kannel service starts all with "-v 4", as I can see by "ps aux | grep kannel".

And for peoples like me :)
Copy your config to some editor, that shows invisible characters,
separate all groups by empty line and don't set space on line end or just use quotes.

Comment: The `-v` parameter is the same as the `log-level` parameter in the conf file. If you pass both, then the parameter in the conf file (`log-level`) will override the command line parameter (`-v`) but if you cannot even get to reading the `log-level` from conf, it sets the most verbose output for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Working config for two SMSC:

```
group = core
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/bearerbox.log"
log-level = 0
access-log = "/var/log/kannel/access_kannel.log"
admin-port = 13000
admin-password = pass
store-file = "/var/log/kannel/store_sms"
smsbox-port = 13001
dlr-storage = internal
sms-resend-retry = 1

group = smsc
smsc-id = receivesend
smsc = smpp
host = **.**.***.***
port = 2775
smsc-username = "***"
smsc-password = "***"
address-range = ""
source-addr-ton = 0
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
system-type = VMA
throughput = 1000
reconnect-delay = 5
connection-timeout = 120
transceiver-mode = true
denied-smsc-id = onlysend
allowed-smsc-id = receivesend
preferred-smsc-id = receivesend

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
sendsms-port = 13005
global-sender = 4105
log-file = /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log
log-level = 0
access-log = /var/log/kannel/access_smsbox.log

group = smsc
smsc-id = onlysend
smsc = smpp
host = **.***.***.***
port = 3102
smsc-username = "***"
smsc-password = "***"
address-range = ""
source-addr-ton = 0
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
system-type = VMA
throughput = 1000
reconnect-delay = 5
connection-timeout = 120
transceiver-mode = true
denied-smsc-id = receivesend
allowed-smsc-id = onlysend
preferred-smsc-id = onlysend

group = sendsms-user
username = "user1"
password = "pass"
concatenation = true
max-messages = 20
default-smsc = receivesend

group = sms-service
keyword = default
post-url = "http://*****.**/sms/%p/time/%t/coding/%c/smsc/%i"
concatenation = true
max-messages = 2

group = sendsms-user
username = "user2"
password = "pass"
concatenation = true
max-messages = 20
default-smsc = onlysend
```